# UnicodeEncodeError in QGIS when setting a path

Tags: qgis-plugins, internationalization, unicode

When I'm trying to batch reproject a bunch of files using `GDAL warp (reproject)` from processing module in QGIS (2.14) I'm getting `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-8: ordinal not in range(128) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\BatchOutputSelectionPanel.py", line 83, in showSelectionDialog
    print filename, selectedFileFilter
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is a **very** common error when working with Russian/Unicode paths (and/or Russian locale of QGIS) and is not specific to this particular module but rather to using any Unicode paths within a workflow.

Is there any way to overcome this error?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How can I avoid UnicodeEncodeError when using geoprocessing tools in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59521/how-can-i-avoid-unicodeencodeerror-when-using-geoprocessing-tools-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Joseph suggested, the problem was due to the bug in the code of the processing sub-module `BatchOutputSelectionPanel.py` (maybe it exists in other modules, though I have not tested it yet).

As `Traceback` suggests, the `UnicodeEncodeError` comes from *line 83:* `print filename, selectedFileFilter`. I checked the source code and have found out that variable `filename` has full unicode support, but `selectedFileFilter`, which stores input file mask and a mask description, has not.

e.g. in Russian locale of QGIS in this case `selectedFileFilter` stores text `Tif-файлы (*.tif)` and the module then tries to encode it as ascii, which causes this error.

The workaround was to switch QGIS locale to English.