# RQGIS R package to use QGIS functions is not working: throwing Error, UnicodeEncodeError / Python?

Tags: qgis, python, r, rqgis

I am currently using 
R ver. 3.4.1 installed on C:\R\R-3.4.1, 
installed and loaded Packages: `RQGIS`, `sp`, `raster`. 
QGIS ver. 2.18.11 installed with OSGeo installer on C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis.

In R I am trying to use the installed RQGIS package to enable QGIS functions via R as shown in the example of the packages GitHub page (https://github.com/jannes-m/RQGIS), I was following.

My environment is set to:

```
set_env()
$root
[1] "C:\\OSGeo4W64"
$qgis_prefix_path
[1] "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis"
$python_plugins
[1] "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins"
```

But unfortunately I always get errors at the following line of code:

```
library("RQGIS")
find_algorithms(search_term = "([Pp]olygon)(centroid)")

Error in py_str_impl(object) : 
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 77807: ordinal not in range(128)
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'getvalue'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:/R/library/reticulate/python\rpytools\output.py", line 14, in end_stdout_capture
    output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
```

I have already tried reinstalling QGIS, R and all depending packages for a couple of times.

Now I checked Spacedman's suggestions, see below.

For R:

```
> reticulate::py_config() 
python:         C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe 
libpython:      C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/python27.dll
pythonhome:     C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27 
version:        2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
Architecture:   64bit 
numpy:          C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy.               
 numpy_version:  1.12.1  
 python versions found:   
 C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe  
 C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\python.exe
```

And in QGIS I entered:

```
import sys 
sys.executable

'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin\\qgis-bin.exe'
```

Unfortunately I still don't know how to get it up running correctly.

Comment: Looks like `reticulate` is causing the error. Do you have the latest CRAN version of `reticulate`?

Comment: Yes, I do have the latest CRAN reticulate version installed. I even deleted the reticulate folder in my library directory and reinstalled the package. But still no success...

Comment: Run `reticulate::py_config()` in R. Then in the QGIS python console do `import sys` and `sys.executable`. The `sys.executable` in QGIS should be the same as the `python:` value in the config. Edit your question and include those outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your Ideas. But I admit I don't know how to use the output your code produces, to correct my errors. I appreciate further advices.

Comment: Right now I assume that your problem goes back to the unicode thing and has nothing to do with `RQGIS`. Have you tried to look for solutions for this problem? See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59521/how-can-i-avoid-unicodeencodeerror-when-using-geoprocessing-tools-in-qgis?rq=1

Comment: @pat-s Yes I was reading both of your suggested stackoverflow-pages before I even posted this question, and after reading them again and spending another couple of hours of trying to reinstall every component of RStudio and OSGeo stuff in hope to fix it, I believe by now it must be something directly concerning python.

Comment: Also my Error changed slightly, since I only get this, without the detailed traceback and different positions, now it is displaying: 
`Error in py_str_impl(object) : 
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 68825: ordinal not in range(128)

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'getvalue'`

If I would know the corresponding python file I could insert a line of code forcing it to use `UTF-8`, but I have no clue where to put It. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not figure out yet to get rid of this error. So I moved away from Windows into the Linux world and got it up running without a problem.

Comment: Still I am interested in a solution, since I got some proprietary software only running on Windows. So further help is still apreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just to give an update on this topic: By now I am able to run QGIS properly on Windows 7. And I like it a lot! Meanwhile I did a lot of updates with the advanced Installation of OSGeo installer though. So unfortunately I can not say why it's finally working, but I am glad it is. Thank you for your efforts and help!

Comment: Hey I'm having the same problem (it is 2019) and I'm trying to run RQGIS using RSTUDIO: platform x86_64-w64-mingw32 arch x86_64 os mingw32 system x86_64, mingw32 status major 3 minor 5.0 year 2018 month 04 day 23 svn rev 74626 language R version.string R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
nickname Joy in Playing does anyone know how to change the "qgis_prefix_path" before you set the environment for RQGIS ????